# Removing duplicate from array of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I start with 2 matrices:

```
a[1] = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
a[2] = {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Then I create 100 matrices in an array, by multiplying the first matrix by the power of the second:

```
f[n_] := a[1].MatrixPower[a[2], n]
operations = Array[f, 100];
```

Now I want to remove duplicate matrices from 'operations' which looks like:

```
{ {matrix 1},{matrix 2}, {matrix 3} ... }
```

Where each matrix is 3x3.

I've tried `DeleteDuplicates[operations]` but it only leaves 2 matrices when their are 24 unique ones.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[operations]` leaves 4 matrices on my Mathematica 11.0 (Ubuntu), and that seems to be correct (note that `MatrixPower[a[2],5] == a[2]`).

Comment: Yep you're right, I wrote down the wrong matrix... Thanks! @anderstood

Answer (score 2):

There are only 4 distinct matrices you can generate this way.
Alternatively you can try `Union[operations]`